# Check Woocommerce Variation Before Adding to Cart

Tags: woocommerce

I am running a T-Shirt store that offers two attributes which users select "Size" and "Color" now what I want is to check the size and color combination which users chooses before adding to cart and restrict users to add specific color and size combination into cart.

So I was wondering if there is any action or filter hook which let me get that functionality.

Comment: Did you have any luck solving this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Thats really simple. Using the default variation menu in the product editor of woocommerce you can do that very easily. The procedure is as follows.

Assume that you have a store where you sell t-shirts of 2 colors (Black,White) and 3 sizes (L,M,S). And not all color t-shirts are in all sizes. Assume that the available combinations are- Black Large, Black Medium, White Medium and White Small. That means your customer mustn't be able to order a Black Small or White Large t-shirt.

Go to the dashboard and create a new product. Choose the product type as variable product and in the attributes tab insert your attributes appropriately. Don't forget to check the select boxes labeled as Visible on the product page and Used for variations. Than go to variations tab and click on add variation button. This will open up the form to add a new product variation.

For this example we'll assume that we have entered two attributes in the attributes tab- Color (Black,White) and Size (L,M,S). In the add variation form you'll see two select boxes labeled according to your attributes entered earlier (any color, any size in this case) and from there you need to select the possible combinations for your product and fill up other information as well. You need to add variation in this way for each of the possible combinations of your product. Don't click on the link all variation button as it'll create each possible combinations for your product and end you up to deleting the unwanted combinations.

There are plenty of other resources on adding a variable product which you may find helpful and step by step. But the main idea of the solution of your problem is discussed above.

Hope this will be helpful.